# Why am I getting "too many arguments"

Tags: shell-script, arguments, test

Here's a part of my script that is telling me that I have too many arguments on line 3:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL='C'
if [ `echo "*file 2" | grep -o ^.` = '.' ]
then
    echo success
fi
```

Anybody know why? As far as I can tell, I'm just comparing two arguments, "*" and "."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo "*file 2" | grep -o ^.` prints `*`.

Since you have a command substitution outside double quotes, it undergoes globbing (a.k.a. wildcard matching a.k.a. filename generation) and word splitting. If the current directory is not empty, `*` expands to the list of files in the current directory. Each file becomes one token in the `[` command, which is highly likely to be a syntax error.

The problem is that you didn't use double quotes around the command substitution. **Always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions** unless you have a good reason to omit them.

```
if [ "$(echo "*file 2" | grep -o ^.)" = '.' ]
```

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to shell scripting, so all help is appreciated!

Comment: single quotes had the same problem though and normally they seemed to work